# How to get the key names from the JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, object

I am creating a page where I want to print the values like below the code snippet using the `map` function in JavaScript.

```
var kvArray = [{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4},{a:5, b:6}];

function getValue(item,index) {
    var vm="<table/>"

    var fullValue =[item.a +" "+ item.b];
    var v=vm+fullValue
    return v;
}

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =kvArray.map(getValue).join(" ")
}
```

I am getting the output like this:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

But I want the actual output like this:

```
a b
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Comment: Try google next time ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: May you please clarify more?

Answer (score 2):

Please see the following snippet for a working example:

```js
var kvArray = [{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4},{a:5, b:6}]
var asCell = v => `<td>${v}</td>`
var asRow = v => `<tr>${v}</tr>`

$('#demo > thead > tr').html(
  Object.keys(kvArray[0]).map(key => asCell(key))
)

$('#demo > tbody').html(
  kvArray.map(entry => {
    return asRow(Object.keys(entry).map(k => {
      return asCell(entry[k])
    }).join())
  })
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="demo">
  <thead>
    <tr></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I used `Object.keys(kvArray[0])` to get the "column names".

Answer (score 0):

```
var kvArray = [{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4},{a:5, b:6}];

function getValue(item,index) 
{
    var vm="<table/>"

    var fullValue =[item.a +" "+ item.b];
    var v=vm+fullValue
    return v;
}

function createTable(kvArray) 
{
    var tableOpening="<table>";
    var tableClosing="</table>";
    var headerOpening= "<th>";
    var headerClosing= "</th>";
    var rowOpening= "<tr>";
    var rowClosing= "</tr>";
    var cellOpening= "<td>";
    var cellClosing= "</td>";

    // get the keys from the first element
    var keys = Object.keys(kvArray && kvArray[0]) ;

    // create a header
    var header = rowOpening;
    for (var keyIndex in keys) {
        header += headerOpening + keys[keyIndex] + headerClosing + "\n";
    }
    header += rowClosing;

    var table = tableOpening + header;

    // create a row for each element
    for (var itemIndex in kvArray) {
      // open the row element
      var rowLine = rowOpening;
      for (var keyIndex in keys) {
        // fill the cells
        rowLine += cellOpening + kvArray[itemIndex][keys[keyIndex]] + cellClosing + "\n";
      }
      // close the row element
      rowLine += rowClosing;

      // add the current row to the table
      table += rowLine;
    }

    // close the table
    table += tableClosing;

    return table;
}
```

Now just use this function for creating a table like so:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = createTable(kvArray);
```

I know this is not as short as some of the answers given here, but it is much simpler to understand, as you obviously lack some concepts, namely your code was creating  in each row and you were lucky it worked.